# Join and nullable values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, view

I have three tables in my `MySql` database :

**Vehicle**

- Id_vehicle_pk( int,auto-increment,pk)
- id_driver_fk(varchar,fk, nullable)

**User**

- Id_user_pk(varchar,pk)
- mail(varchar)

**Collaborator**

- Id_coll_pk(int,pk)
- Id_user_fk(varchar,fk)
- First_Name(varchar)
- Last_Name(varchar)

I'd like to create a view which join these three tables, so i try this

```
select Id_vehicle_pk, id_driver_fk,mail, Id_coll_pk, First_Name,Last_Name
from 
  Vehicle join User join 
  Collaborator 
where 
  `Vehicle`.`id_driver_fk` = `User`.`Id_user_pk` 
  and `Collaborator`.`Id_user_fk` = `User`.`Id_user_pk`
group by Id_vehicle_pk
Having Id_vehicle_pk> 0
```

But I have wrong result caused by null values of `id_driver_fk`. So I need to know :

1. How can I fix my query?

Comment: put where clause `WHERE id_driver_fk IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @tinka `Id_vehicle_pk` is a primary key it can't be null !!!!

Comment: You are not joining the tables using the key columns. Are you sure you posted the working code?

Comment: *wrong results* is not very clear. please edit your question to include some sample data, expected results and current results. Also, if it's MySql please remove the Sql server tag.

Comment: And now you are mixing explicit join with implicit joins. stop using implicit joins. they are out of date for over 20 years now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `LEFT JOIN` clause which allows to get all records from the main table even if there are no foreign key matches to other tables:

```
SELECT 
     v.Id_vehicle_pk, 
     v.id_driver_fk, 
     u.mail,  
     c.Id_coll_pk, 
     c.First_Name,  
     c.Last_Name
FROM Vehicle v LEFT JOIN 
     User u ON v.id_driver_fk  = u.Id_user_pk LEFT JOIN
     Collaborator c ON c.Id_user_fk = u.Id_user_pk
WHERE Id_vehicle_pk> 0
```

Also it is a best practice to put join condition inside the join rather than `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `on` clause in both of your joins.

```
select Id_vehicle_pk, 
       id_driver_fk, 
       mail, Id_coll_pk, 
       First_Name,
       Last_Name
from Vehicle 
join User on id_driver_fk = Id_user_pk
join Collaborator on Id_user_pk = Id_user_fk
group by Id_vehicle_pk
Having Id_vehicle_pk> 0
```